# How to get each value in an array and show it in a listbox

Tags: vb.net-2010

Hi I am new to VB and I have problems with using array. My code is like that.
This is class FindFactorsObject.vb

```
Public Sub FindFactors()
    count = 0
    temp = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(_x))
    For i As Integer = 1 To temp
        If _x Mod i = 0 Then
            ReDim array(count)
            array(count) = i
            count += 1
        End If
    Next
```

So I created an array and stored the results. Now I want to display each value in my array in Form.vb and if it is possible can somebody teach me how to make delay for each of the displayed value. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Always declare your variables, if possible to their exact types, you think they will take care of. When you say 'Now I want to display each value in my array in Form.vb' I understood literally: in the Form so, we will print them on your form

```
Public Sub FindFactors(_x As Integer)
    Dim temp As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(_x))
    Dim l As New List(Of Integer)
    For i As Integer = 1 To temp
        If _x Mod i = 0 Then
            l.add(i)
        End If
    Next
    Dim pf As New PointF(20, 20)
    For Each i As Integer In l
        creategraphics.drawstring(i.ToString, New font(font.fontFamily, 24), brushes.cadetblue, pf)
        pf = New PointF(pf.X, pf.Y + 30)
    Next
End Sub
```